# Dell PowerEdge RAID controller: Configuration of NVRAM and drives mismatch(Normal mismatch)

Tags: raid, hard-drive, dell

The question is what is the reason of this problem and how can i solve it without losing data on disk

When server boots the following messages appears:

[image: PowerEdge Expandable RAID Controller BIOS]

[image: system Disk Configuration]

bios of raid controller
[image: Image capture 1]
configuration of disk
[image: Image capture 2]

Comment: You might want to also "View NVRAM Configuration" and see how it differs.

Comment: Looks like the drives have one type of configuration while the controller configuration specifies a different configuration. Newer devices detect this AND give you an option to update nvram according to the disk configuration. Check both and see where they differ as already suggested.